# Firebase Error when syncing Gradle

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-services

I am having this error when syncing gradle 
I have installed `Google repository` and also `Google play services` in the `SDK Manager` but i am still getting this error !

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/11.4.0/play-services-ads-11.4.0.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/11.4.0/play-services-ads-11.4.0.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/11.4.0/play-services-ads-11.4.0.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/11.4.0/play-services-ads-11.4.0.jar
Required by:
project :
```

Here is my Gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ytstudios.wall.bucket"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
}
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.0'


//Firebase Plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the classpath :

```
classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'
```

Comment: You have to do 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'
Source: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Nope, still getting the error

Comment: can you share the project level gradle file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :
Compiled the class path `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`
And added repository

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
```

Also compiled 
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'` in Project Gradle

Comment: Nice and elegant.